# Expression is not assignable error when comparing two nodes

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an object of type ControlPointNode that derives from an abstractNode that itself derives from SKSpriteNode and I have the following code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//we look at teh number of touches
for (UITouch *touch in touches)
{

    ...

        _positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode * touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:_positionInScene];

      ...

                for (ControlPointNode *controlPoint in _controlPointsVector) {

                    if (controlPoint.position.x = touchedNode.position.x){

                      // do something
                    }
   …
```

The problem is that I receive an error message saying ***Expression is not assignable*** in the line:

***if (controlPoint.position.x = touchedNode.position.x){***

Can anyone help with a solution to this error, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
if (controlPoint.position.x == touchedNode.position.x){
```

because

```
if (controlPoint.position.x = touchedNode.position.x){
```

tries to assign `controlPoint.position.x` to `touchedNode.position.x` instead of comparing them.

<sup>As side note: If you'll really want to assign `controlPoint.position.x` to `touchedNode.position.x` somewhere, it won't work and you'll have to use `controlPoint.position = CGPointMake(touchedNode.position.x, controlPoint.position.y)`.</sup>